# Transfer token from smart contract to 2 EOA addresses

Tags: solidity, tokens

There is an escrow smart contact which at the end needs to send the escrow balance back to both `seller` and `buyer`. Here is the contract (without all the details)

```
pragme ^0.7.0;

interface ERC20Token {...};

contract MyEscrow {
  address payable seller;
  address payable buyer;
  uint256 sellerRefund;
  uint256 buyerRefund;
  address addressToken;

  function depositEscrow(uint256 _amount) external returns (bool) {
    ERC20Token(addressToken).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);  //<<==msg.sender approved before calling depositEscrow()
    //do something else
  }

  function refundEscrow() sellerOnly external returns (bool) {
      ERC20Token(addressToken).transfer(seller, sellerRefund);
      ERC20Token(addressToken).transfer(buyer, buyerRefund);
      //do something
  }

}
```

Before putting the code into test, is the `refundEscrow` going to work as expected? Here is the [example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46318/how-can-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-from-a-contract-to-an-user-account/46360) online which only sends refund to `msg.sender`. In the code above, the difference is that refund is sent to 2 recipients instead.

Comment: This will work as long as `_amount` in `depositEscrow()` is greater than `sellerRefund + buyerRefund`.

Comment: Sure, they are equal now. _amount == sellerRefund + buyerRefund.

Comment: `Shane Fontaine`, one thing puzzles me was that msg.value can not be used to represent value of ERC20 token. msg.value can only be used for `ether`. sent with transaction.